# Does a coroutine call boost::asio::write block the current thread？

Tags: boost-asio, boost-beast, boost-beast-websocket

When the coroutine calls boost::asio::write, the coroutine will block waiting for the buffer to become writable or the coroutine will be scheduled out because the tcp buffer is full？

Answer (score 0):

The `read` call is blocking, so yes, regardless of whether you are in a coroutine it blocks. This is documented: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_82_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/read/overload1.html

> "The call will block until one of the following conditions is true: [...]"

Now, if you're looking at simplifying async code with coroutines you can "just" substitute

```
 x = XYZ(a, b, c);
```

With

```
 x = co_await async_XYZ(a, b, c, asio::use_awaitable);
```

### PRO TIP: Default completion tokens

You can bind the default completion token (`use_awaitable` here) to an executor, and use that with your IO object. See [as_default_on](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_82_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/use_awaitable_t/as_default_on.html) and the examples that use it. Then your code can become

```
 x = co_await async_XYZ(a, b, c);
```

Comment: Edit: I forgot to insert async_ due to copy/paste...

Comment: golang encapsulates the network io system call and coroutines it if there is a block. Why doesn't asio do the same?

Comment: Because it doesn't assume you accept the overhead. For example you can use Asio without any threads. You can integrate it with another framework that supplies the event loop (eg a game engine) etc. As usual C++ favors genericity and low cost over convenience

Comment: By the way "golang coroutines it if there's a block" to me sounds like a confused way of saying it's nonblocking. I'm not well versed with golang to know whether there is some special hidden feature you are referring to, but I can't readily think of anything.